# ASP.NET Core View Component model scope

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I'm trying to create a reusable view component for a select box populated from a lookup service, which can also handle client side validation based on the parent's viewmodel.

My component is being called like so:

```
<vc:lookup asp-for="Gender" lookup-name="Gender"></vc:lookup>
```

Where Gender is a property on my viewmodel that has standard required attributes on for both client/server side validation.

My component takes the lookup name and queries the database for the options to choose from:

```
public IViewComponentResult Invoke(string aspFor, string lookupName)
{
    var items = _lookupService.GetAllLookups(lookupName).Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.Name, Value = x.Value.ToString() });
    return View(new LookupViewModel(aspFor, items));
}
```

And then finally being rendered inside my components view:

```
<label asp-for="@Model.AspFor"></label>
<div class="select-container">
    <select asp-for="@Model.AspFor" asp-items="@Model.Items">
        <option value="">Please Select</option>
    </select>
</div>
<span asp-validation-for="@Model.AspFor"></span>
```

It is now obvious to me that this is never going to work, as the model for the lookup has to be generic, and therefore will never contain the annotations needed to enforce required fields etc.

What I'm looking to do is somehow use the parent model scope within this view component, so the properties on the viewmodel for the containing form are available for me inside this component. Is this possible?

Comment: Did you ever manage to figure this problem out? If not, what did you do as an alternative implementation? Thanks!

Comment: I don't believe we did, and I can't remember what we ended up doing instead either! I don't work at the same company anymore so don't even have access to check the code.